# Confused about the load factor for the hashtable with collisions

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I'm confused about load factors for such hashtables.
I know that in order to compute the load factor, we need to divide the number of entries by number of slots we have and when the load factor reaches 0.75 it has to rehash.

So, what is "number of entires" for this hashtable? Total number of keys or total number of indices that these keys occupy.

Because if it is total number of keys, what would be the point of rehashing ? It would just waste the space and time.
And if it is total number of just indices occupied, so then the load factor will be 2/5 = 0.4?

[image]

Comment: The number of entries is the number of keys, yes, since every key has one and only one associated value, and an entry is a key/value pair. The point f rehashing such a map is precisely to avoid this long linked list which harms the performance of the map, and distribute the entries among buckets in a better way. An ideal distribution is when each bucket has 0 or 1 entry only.

Comment: But when such collisions occur, rehashing would not help, right? Only changing the hashFunction would work?

Comment: No. Let's take a simple example, where the map has 3 buckets, and a simple modulo of the hash code is used to choose the bucket. Let's say you have 0, 3 and 6 in the map. They all would be in the bucket 0, because 0 % 3 == 0, 3 % 3 == 0 and 6 % 3 == 0. Now let's rehash, and use 7 buckets instead. Now 0 % 7 == 0, so the first key goes to the bucket 0. 3 % 7 == 3, so 3 ends up in the bucket 3. 6 % 7 == 6, so the key 6 goes to the bucket 6. And the keys are now ideally distributed among buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Number of entries is the number of key-value mappings in the map, as returned by
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#size--
or alternatively, the number of elements in the `Set` returned by 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--

This matches our intuition about what a map is, a collection of key-value pairs, so each pair is one entry.

Per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html the number of entries is compared to the product of the load factor `fac`, an arbitrary parameter, and the capacity, `cap`, the current number of buckets.

You think of "when the load factor reaches", but that is not correct. The load factor does not change after construction. By default it is `0.75`, sufficient for pretty much all uses.

Think instead of `threshold` the product `threshold = fac * cap;`.
The threshold only changes when `cap` changes, because `fac` does not.

What does change all the time is `nentries`, the number of entries currently in the map.

(I'm just making up variable names to simplify this answer. They have nothing to do with actual Java API source code.)

Your diagram shows five buckets, so `threshold = (int)(0.75 * 5)` or `3`.

The decision to rehash is `if (nentries >= threshold)`. You have ten entries in your picture, so yes, that map needs a rehash. Actually, it would have rehashed on the third entry, increasing `cap` to approximately ten entries, depending on the implementation. On the eighth entry, the capacity would grow to twenty, so ten entries would then be less than the new threshold, `threshold = 0.75 * 20`, or `16`.

Comment: That is a little bit confusing! Since according to other articles, load factor = number of entries/number of slots. In that particular example it would be 2, wouldn't be?